# New Agile PM Software

Tags: project-management, agile, saas

There is a new Agile software tool on the Market. It is very lightweight and easy to use. I cannot remember the name of it and it is not coming up in any of my searches. I want to say its called velocity or something. But I cant seem to get it down. If anyone know's what I am talking about then please reply.

Comment: I suspect you're getting your name from Veracity which is a Distributed Version Control System (http://veracity-scm.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are talking about Upvise (http://upvise.com/)

"Upvise provides mobile on-demand sync & collaboration software and hosted services for small businesses. With Upvise, you can organize and share information with your co-workers, and sync data between all the mobile phones and web accounts in your company."

Comment: I found what I was talking about. Check out... http://apptrajectory.com and http://trello.com